# How to create/file certificate for SharePoint App

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory, sharepoint-2013, digital-certificate

We have a SharePoint Server in a farm with SQL Server and Active Directory Server. and we are trying to create a self-signed certificate for use in SP App. The farm is hosted on CloudShare and we are unsure if the certificate is provided? or if you have manually create one. 
if we have to manually create one, can you provide steps on how to do so?

Thanks

Comment: how come this is a sql-server question? please use tags properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a self-sign certificate from IIS for your local development.
Please follow the below url it will help you to create the self-sign certificate
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shariq/2013/05/07/how-to-set-up-high-trust-apps-for-sharepoint-2013-troubleshooting-tips/

Comment: Thank you so much @Rahul